# Tracking progress when using PromiseKit and Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, promisekit

Is there any idiomatic way to track execution progress using [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/)? For example with [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) downloading progress?

Comment: That is a job for RxSwift, ReactiveKit, Interstellar, or one of the other reactive libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can see **@mxcl** (creator of [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)) commented about that: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/127#issuecomment-103668741

Basically, you can use the `NSProgress` to track the progress of a network task. Alamofire supports that, have a look at the documentation: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/c563be562f3c9ff327919bb88599e3082db3abda/Documentation/Usage.md#download-progress